# How to do I save a file that has been put into the clipboard?

Tags: finder, ms-office, copy-paste

I'm using a program that exports an image to the clipboard.
If I goto Finder->Edit->"Show Clipboard" a windows pops up showing the image.

How do I save this image to the Finder?  If I goto the Finder->Edit-> "paste" is greyed out.

Things I've tried:

- pbpaste doesn't seem to see the image but the man page seems to
  insinuate that it only understands Encapsulated  PostScript  (EPS)
  .ps files
- New from Clipboard in SnagIt works but I'm guessing that it creates a
  new file and I'd like to get the original file.
- Paste into PowerPoint puts the file there...but I can't seem to take
  it out of there.  IE, dragging the image from PowerPoint to Finder
  doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this without using another app to be able to paste to, then save the result, but I suspect the cause is that the image in the clipboard isn't a file at all yet, it's just 'an image'. You need to be able to get it to something that can make it into a file.

Comment: @Tetsujin is correct. And also the idea that a digital copy of something in the clipboard is different, somehow, than something you paste into SnagIt (or anything else) is incorrect. Finder is nothing more than a file manager for other programs. Even the show clipboard function is an app that the Finder calls to display the contents of the clipboard.

Comment: As an aside, in PowerPoint you can right / ctrl click on the image -> save picture

Comment: @Tim when I do the save as picture in PowerPoint, it only seems to save as PNG and I think that the original is a pdf.  So I think that it's converting it.

Comment: @SteveChambers, I think the same thing is happening as well with SnagIt, the picture is being converted.  One of the reasons i think that is that the resolution is visibly reduced.

Comment: @Alex A pdf is not an image. Is it exporting an image or a pdf to the clipboard? If it is a pdf, preview, as suggested in the top answer below, should cope.

Comment: @Tim Honestly, that is what I was trying to figure out and what prompted the question. Turns outs it's a PDF.

Comment: @Alex in that case, yes preview or the free software Inkscape may be able to cope (although Inkscape limits to 1 page I think).

Comment: The Preview answer is gold.  Using that, and then then save as, Preview seems smart enough to save as a PDF or a PNG or a JPG depending on what's originally on the Clipboard when I do CMD+N ( File -> New from Clipboard )

Comment: I vote to reopen this as the related question is asking about resolution too, whereas this is as simple as 'how do I save a file that's on the clipboard', and since there's many ways to do it, it would be useful for there to be some more answers.

Comment: If you want to save an image on clipboard *using the terminal*, [this](https://superuser.com/a/794070/928461) answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An easy way is to use the built-in Preview app.

1. Copy the image.
2. Open Preview.
3. Press: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

   - A new window will open with your copied image.
4. On the menu bar, click File > Save, or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and a Save As sheet will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try Notes app. Or email. They can take copied files. Then you can right click and save where you want.

Comment: I picked the Preview answer because Notes and Mail seem to pass it through Preview.  This was also helpful though, Thanks.

Comment: I imagined that it was a non-photo file (like pdf, doc, zip etc), of which a thumbnail "image" is seen in show clipboard.

Comment: Turns out it was a PDF. (had assumed it was a PNG until getting the above answers)